# Sequencing with baffle.js:

Tags: javascript

I've looked around & still not sure how to best approach creating 'sequences' with the baffle.js library (working on it for an artist client).

Essentially the idea is to switch the 'options' every X seconds over a long period of time, & I thought this would be doable by simply using the 'stop' method, & resetting it etc.:

```
var b = baffle('.baffle');
b.start();
b.set({speed: 50, characters: 'XX'}).reveal(1000);
b.stop;
b.set({speed: 200, characters: 'AA'}).reveal(2000);
```

But only the second 'set' method is called. Will I need to call baffle methods within a broader logic?